# psmouse serio1 unknown hardware and mouse/touchpad works ONLY in rescue mode

Tags: centos

I'm getting this error on my laptop:

> psmouse serio1: elantech: unknown hardware version, aborting

As a result the mouse is not functioning. I can use the mouse/touchpad when I am in Linux rescue mode.
The grub list is as follows:

```
Centos Linux (3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64) 7 (Core)
Centos Linux (3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64) 7 (Core)
Centos Linux (O-rescue-..) 7 (Core)
```

I installed using the Minimal ISO of Centos then updated it and installed GNOME desktop and some development and multimedia plug-ins. I rebooted after each installation and in all instances the mouse worked.

With the first two options it worked after installing the OS but since early this morning it doesn't work. In the rescue option it still does.

So is there a way to rescue/restore back to the old setting or to populate the configurations that are in the rescue mode into the main Centos mode.

This is CentOS 7 on an Lenovo Ideapad Notebook.

Comment: First step is to `dmesg > some_file` after boot for both rescue mode and normal mode, and have a look if there are differences wrt. the mouse/touchpad.